How to make translucent image in Java with swing?
I am making a game using Java's swing.
There is a part during the game where a certain image needs to be exposed on the screen with 50% transparency, but I don't know how to make that image transparent.
If you know, please let me know.
I searched for this information on the Internet, but all I found was about making the window itself transparent or removing the background behind the image.
I also thought about using another program to make the original image transparent and insert it into a separate source file, but not only was it not perfect, but it felt different from the background screen in the game, so I gave up.
I'm not familiar with English, so I used a translator. I would appreciate your understanding even if there is poor grammar.

I don't want to remove the background of a specific image, I want the image itself to be transparent.

Example Image:

However, other questions that were found to be similar to my question are not about this, but are asking about how to erase the background of an image and getting an answer to it. This does not fit my purpose.

@AndrewYim the OP wrote explicity that they don't want to remove the background - but your linked article shows that as solution.

In this old Java tutorial about working with images you can see some example code in the topic Filtering that should exactly do what you need: draw a picture with 50% transparency.

import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TranslucentImage extends JLabel {

   void iniciar() {
      JFrame fra = new JFrame( "Translucent" );
      fra.setDefaultCloseOperation( javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
      fra.setBounds( 100, 100, 400, 400 );
      fra.requestFocusInWindow();
      fra.setFocusable( true );
      fra.setLayout( null );
      JPanel a = new JPanel(),
              b = new JPanel();
      a.setBounds( 0, 0, 200, 400 );
      b.setBounds( 200, 0, 200, 400 );
      setBounds( 100, 100, 200, 200 );
      a.setBackground( Color.red );
      b.setBackground( Color.blue );
      fra.add( this );
      fra.add( a );
      fra.add( b );
      fra.setVisible( true );
   }

   @Override
   public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
      super.paintComponent( g );
      Graphics2D gr = ( Graphics2D ) g;
      AlphaComposite ac = AlphaComposite
              .getInstance( AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.5f );
      gr.setComposite( ac );
      gr.setColor( Color.yellow );
      gr.fillRect( 0, 0, 200, 200 );
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      TranslucentImage aa = new TranslucentImage();
      aa.iniciar();
   }
}

To make the JLabel show a transparent drawing, we overwrite the paintComponent() method, and before drawing our rectangle, we add the line:
AlphaComposite transparency = AlphaComposite
      .getInstance( AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.5f );

which sets the transparency to 0.5 (via the float 0.5f).
Then we set the Graphics2D object to that value:
gra.setComposite( transparency );

that will make the rectangle to be drawn as we require.
Note: for this example, I have used two JPanel, placed side by side, so you can see the difference due to the transparency, it is important the order in which they are added to the JFrame (add()) since it determines who is drawn on top of who (you can also use setComponentZOrder).
You can get to the same scheme, just by drawing in the JLabel, first the solid rectangles and then the transparent one, something like:
public class TranslucentImage extends JLabel {

   void iniciar() {
      JFrame fra = new JFrame( "Translucent" );
      fra.setDefaultCloseOperation( javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
      fra.setBounds( 100, 100, 400, 400 );
      fra.requestFocusInWindow();
      fra.setFocusable( true );
      fra.setLayout( null );
      setBounds( 0, 0, 400, 400 );
      fra.add( this );          
      fra.setVisible( true );
   }

   @Override
   public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
      super.paintComponent( g );
      Graphics2D gr = ( Graphics2D ) g; 
       gr.setColor( Color.red );
       gr.fillRect( 0, 0, 200, 400 );
       gr.setColor( Color.blue );
       gr.fillRect( 200, 0, 200, 400 );          
      AlphaComposite ac = AlphaComposite
              .getInstance( AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.5f );
      gr.setComposite( ac );
      gr.setColor( Color.yellow );
      gr.fillRect( 100, 100, 200, 200 );
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      TranslucentImage aa = new TranslucentImage();
      aa.iniciar();
   }
}


I would like to sincerely thank you for your help. Thanks to you, I was able to finish my project. Thank you very much again. I wish you a good day.

@B0N0N0B0, Glad to have helped you, good day to you too!.
